# Highlighting code with mouse goes wild in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to highlight some code in Visual Studio code it goes crazy and moves very fast. E.g. I want to select around one page and end up selecting 10 "pages" worth of code.

How can I make it act normaly when I want to highlight some code?

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same issue. A weird behavior with mouse selection. This was my solution path.

#### Check for hardware failures.

- Unplug the keyboard dongle. If suddenly the mouse selection goes well. Do this steps.
- Check for keys stucked ✅
- Uninstall the keyboard driver from Device Manager ✅
- Change the dongle USB port ✅

And after all this steps, my cursor comes back to normality... for a while .

- Made the keyboard check with [keyboard tester](https://www.keyboardtester.com/)
- Detect the key with the failure (Fortunately <kbd>Insert</kbd> in my case).
- Download the app **keytweak** and disable that key.

This is a workaround if you don´t want to buy a new keyboard. I hope your failing key isn't any vocal . If so... buy a new one.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have not tried your suggestions yet, but it only does that in VS code and in e.g. SSMS and other apps it is fine... If it is my keyboard how come it only does this in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by disablling Vim extension [vim pluggin for vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9sr2.png)